# Merging edited data back into ArcSDE master geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, fme-form

I need some suggestions/inspiration for a problem we have.

**The problem:**

We have an ArcSDE master GIS database. We will edit this data almost exclusively outside of ArcGIS and outside of ArcSDE. In other words, we will make an export of some small area and edit this. Then we will push this data back into an other SDE table (diff database).
We will also maintain an extra attribute that contains: add, delete, edit.

What we want to do now is write this diff table to the master. My question is what is the best tool for doing this?
Using Arcpy with cursor, using FME, or are there other Arcgis tools to help?
I was thinking using ArcPy and doing something like this:

- simply add all objects with status add.
- search for every id with status delete and delete it
- search for all ids with status edit and copy the edited ones

What do you think would be the best tool to do this?

- Arcpy?
- FME
- direct SQL (we are using MS SQL)
- others...

The master database will be in the range of about 500.000 objects, so performance is maybe an issue. At the moment we are thinking about a sync operation where an operator starts the sync and can wait for it to finish so he can do some checks after it is completed.

Bonus questions:
We will need to sync dimensionings and labels too. The problem is that, in the diff database, we probably cannot store them as arcgis dimensioning feature classes but they will be line and point symbols with the necessary data attachted to it. Can we use the same technique for transforming and migrating this data so it fits in the dimensioning classes?

Comment: Just so you're aware, you can't alter tables via SQL if you're using versioning. ArcGIS won't be able to "see" the changes.

Comment: With the inclusion of your "Bonus questions" I think this Question becomes broader than the "one question per Question" that assists clean Q&A.  I recommend that you edit your Question to remove them and, if they are still important, to research/ask them separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An approach that I have used successfully and seems to perform pretty well in FME is to create three columns in the "master" feature class on SDE:

1. A field containing the feature's original OID (or other unique ID).
2. (Optional) A field containing the feature's original feature class name (used if you have multiple source feature classes going into the master feature class)
3. A column containing a CRC ([Cyclic Redundancy Check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)) value for each feature. This value is generated using the [CRCCalculator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2012/html/FME_Transformers/transformers/crccalculator.htm) transformer. See also this [FMEpedia article](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Creating-a-Unique-identifier-using-CRCCalculator) detailing how this can be implemented.

I then read in both the source feature class and the master feature class and "join" (using a [FeatureMerger](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2012/html/FME_Transformers/transformers/featuremerger.htm)) on a concatenation of the original ID and source feature class name.

Now depending on which port the feature leaves the FeatureMerger you know if it's an add, delete or if the feature exists in both places.

You then just need to calculate the CRC again on the incoming feature and compare it against the stored CRC. If the CRC is different, it's an update. If it's the same the feature hasn't changed.

You then know whether to update, delete, add or skip each feature. Just be careful to route the correct streams (input vs. master) and don't mix up the `geodb_oid` values as you'll want to use the master's OIDs for deletes and updates. For adds it doesn't matter. Note the AttributeRenamer step in the FMEpedia example; they used this to avoid the FeatureMerger overwriting existing attributes.

The FMEpedia example sends each database transacation type (update/delete/add) to separate writers, but you can use a neat trick to use only one writer by setting the `fme_db_operation` attribute to UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE and setting the writer mode to UPDATE. This technique is detailed in this [FMEpedia article](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Using-Feature-Based-Attributes-for-Database-updates).

You can also of course add timestamp columns to record when a feature was first loaded and last modified with the [TimeStamper](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2012/html/FME_Transformers/transformers/timestamper.htm) transformer.

Note that this approach would likely allow you to skip the "diff' table step entirely, and I believe that FME also supports dimension and annotation feature classes just fine, so hopefully the approach works the same or only needs minor modifications for those (never used them myself).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't use FeatureMerger, because I can use the "ADD/EDIT/DELETE" fields. I did use the fme_db_operation. the technique described in the article is perfect. Now I still need to check out how I will do the dimensioning and annotation classes, but the first step is allready working.

Answer (score 1):

If you `Registering as versioned with the option to move edits to base` and store your data using SQL Server Spatial type instead of SDE Binary then you can edit your data directly using SQL Server and ArcGIS will see the changes.

Then, you can consider using SQL Server replication (such as Merge replication) techniques to extract a copy of the data a offsite for offline editing.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought would be to use stored procedures in MS SQL to achieve this. I dont have any metrics but I would **assume** it will be by far the quickest way as it would be 'native' What you are asking is pretty straight forward. Just a loop through the diff table issuing sql statements to the master db.

I don't know enough about dimensioning FC though, so I can't help you on this! I would assume that in this case you would have to use ArcPy as it will know how to store the objects in the geodatabase. Unless of course you find out (reverse engineer) what tables are getting updated when a dimensioning class is created.

Comment: Is the mapping between ArcSDE and MS SQL 1 to 1, in other words, is all the information of one object stored in one table in MS SQL or will I have to write to some different tables?

Comment: No, there are many many different tables that make up a feature class. Here's a visual overview: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/002p/pdf/sdesystables_diagram.pdf

Comment: That maybe so, but its all metadata IF you don't do any editing with ESRI tools AND IF the data is stored in MS SQL native format which seems to be the case. If for example, you have a spatial table in MS-SQL and you add a geometry record to it using command line SQL the new record would be displayed in ArcMap. I have tried this using Oracle data and it works fine

Comment: @blah238 thanks for the overview. mapoholic, for the moment I'm using fme because it seems to perform well enough. If this doesn't work out though, I might look at using MS SQL directly.